# Can't use vba flex grid msflxgrd.ocx in ms-access

Tags: vba, ms-access, activex, msflexgrid

I wish to use a flex grid in my access form. I downloaded and registered msflxgrd.ocx successfully. It now appears in the list of insertable ActiveX controls in forms design, so all seems OK. But when I select the control named "Microsoft FlexGrid Control, version 6.0", I get the following error:

> Microsoft Office Access doesn't support this ActiveX control

What's happening here? I am using Access 2007 - do I need a different control and is the one I tried to use supported by Access 2003 only? Or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCX components can be disabled because they could be malicious if they are used in a browser.
To make this component work, you need to edit the registry:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX Compatibility\Compatibility Flags
Change Value from 1024 to ) for CLSID {6262D3A0-531B-11CF-91F6-C2863C385E30}, or the CLSID of your OCX Component.

Comment: Tried this - including restart - and at first it seemed not to work but on inspection the Compatibility flag value was back to 1024 (?!?). Changed again, now no restart and something changed all right: I now get the error message **You don't have the license required to use this ActiveX control** ... I thought it was freeware...:-(

Comment: Try doing the following: 

1. Create manually a .reg file (e.g. FlexGrid.reg) as below and import it to Registry by double clicking.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

// FlexGrid Control 6.0 license key
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\1F3D5522-3F42-11d1-B2FA-00A0C908FB55]
@="gcfjdjecpchcncdjpdejijgcrdoijjfcieod"

Comment: No luck :-( the reg entry was created OK, but I still get the same error when trying to use the control (did a restart too but that did not solve it either - reg key was still there). This is becoming a little awkward - although I am learning more about registry entries, I still fail to be able to use the flexGrid - where all the time it should be part of MS anyway (well, maybe not in 64 bit mode what was the reason for me to register it ...)

Comment: @Maestro13 -- Was there a solution? I'm at the "You don't have the license ..." stage!

Comment: @MartinF Afraid not. And I did not pursue the matter any more since 2012. No idea what the solution is.

Comment: @Maestro13: I'm thinking that, at this late stage in Access development, i'll have to use some of the more advanced features of the built-in controls and maybe some cross-tab queries or pivot tables...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, or what I believe is the same problem, with Access 97 and the TreeView control (which is actually from VB 5.0).

Even though I found and tried Vbcmpfix.exe, and it claimed to add the licenses I needed, it didn't.  I also tried registering and unregistering and replacing the ocx.  I tried this with the 64-bit cmd.exe and the 32-bit.  No change at all.

MS VB5/6 licenses apparently all live in HKCR\Licenses.

I was able to solve this "You don't have the license required" error by exporting that branch from a working XP box and running that .reg in W7 64.

There's also a collection of vb6 license registry entries floating out there called VB6Controls.reg.  It had what would appear to be the same values in it, and I tried it on a different box and it also worked right away.

I had to create an account just to share this solution.  I found dozens of web pages with people unable to solve this, so perhaps this will help someone.